# POX Openflow - Host_Tracker not raising HostEvent

Tags: networking, openflow, mininet, pox, sdn

I am trying to handle host events in POX. So i created a class

```
class DynaRouteStateHandler(object):
 def __init__ (self):
  def startup():
    core.openflow_discovery.addListeners(self)
    core.host_tracker.addListeners(self)
  core.call_when_ready(startup, ('openflow','openflow_discovery','host_tracker'))          

 def _handle_HostEvent (self, event):
      print "CALLED"
```

However i cant see the message called. Also when i try to pingall in mininet, I get a lot of such messages

```
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 3 2 5a:89:55:b5:5a:5f moved to 1 2
WARNING:host_tracker:Possible duplicate: 3 2 5a:89:55:b5:5a:5f at time 1425142891, now (1 2), time 1425142892
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 2 1 76:4e:52:91:1b:2b moved to 3 1
WARNING:host_tracker:Possible duplicate: 2 1 76:4e:52:91:1b:2b at time 1425142891, now (3 1), time 1425142892
```

Any idea why its raising such strange warnings? Also why the the handle_HostEvent function is not getting called?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you name your function correctly.

Generally Ryu is better.